# ffmpeg build thumbnail sequence while transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg

With the goal of improving performance while processing a video file and outputting it into 3 parallel output files, would it be possible to also build a thumbnail sequence as another parallel output or in another process?

To create the 3 parallel outputs, I'm following the example on this page: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

...and using this example:

```
ffmpeg -i input \
    -s 1280x720 -acodec … -vcodec … output1 \
    -s 640x480  -acodec … -vcodec … output2 \
    -s 320x240  -acodec … -vcodec … output3
```

My command to generate thumbnails looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -ss 2 -r "1/3" -s 100x50 ./thumbs/th-%04d.png
```

I'm using the **ffmpeg 4.1**

What I'm finding is that building a series of thumbnails, say 1 every 10 seconds, can be quite time consuming for large video files, so I'm guessing I could save some processing time if I could build the thumbs at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, just add the output

```
ffmpeg -i input \
    -s 1280x720 -acodec … -vcodec … output1 \
    -s 640x480  -acodec … -vcodec … output2 \
    -s 320x240  -acodec … -vcodec … output3 \
    -f image2 -ss 2 -r "1/3" -s 100x50 ./thumbs/th-%04d.png
```

Comment: Windows bit me again... this wasn't working because I did not escape the % in the .bat file I was using for testing. Doh!